# Is it correct to apply standard techniques for a confidence interval calculation to the result of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, confidence-interval

so I have a binary classier from which I can evaluate on a test set and get a proportion (p) of which the classier has correctly gotten right. I then apply the following function to determine the 95% confidence interval.

$$
 CIBounds = \pm 1.96 * \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}
$$

Although my first initial thought was I believe this assumes the underlying distribution is normal. In my lectures this was never really addressed, how would I go around justifying using this approach (or not using it) for my neural network.

Comment: Sure I will remove the last question

Answer (score 1):

The formula which you provided is used for a binomial (distribution) proportion confidence interval, and as you mentioned, it relies on the normal distribution and is only an approximation. In general the formula is quite accurate for values close to 0.5, but can be quite off for values close to the limits (in fact it will go over the possible limits).

There are exact methods to estimate this CI, although the expression is a little more complicated. In any case, if you use this formula to estimate the CI for a proportion coming from a neural network (although I don't know why), you will be making some assumptions about the underlying distribution. If you are not willing to do that, you are better off using non-parametric approaches.

Comment: I'm not married to the idea of calculating confidence intervals I was thinking it might be some nice analysis of the results (I'm still questioning if it adds any significant benefit to my thesis though). 

Can you recommend some other methods (maybe the one your mentioned with the slightly more complicated expression?)

Comment: @JohnTracey See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval.

Comment: Ah nice Wilsons looks good thanks! Although i'm trying to find an example of discussion about using the Wilson score for non-normal data, can you suggest any (I just want to cite something in my thesis really).

Comment: @JohnTracey Try `Wallis, Sean A. (2013). "Binomial confidence intervals and contingency tests: mathematical fundamentals and the evaluation of alternative methods" (PDF). Journal of Quantitative Linguistics. 20 (3): 178–208. doi:10.1080/09296174.2013.799918. S2CID 16741749.`